# Why won't this php upload script work?

Tags: php, html, file, date, upload

I have a html form with file input named image that points to a php file with this code:

```
$date =  date( "Y_m_d_H_i_s_u" );

function upload() {

$info = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
$target = "uploads/" . $date . $info['extension'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}
}
```

I want the filename to have the time in it instead of the  original filename.  I can't figure out why this won't work!  All the uploaded files are named the extension.  Somehow the date won't work.

Comment: variable scope. $date is defined outside the function: pass it as a parameter and you're set.

Comment: Problem is variable scope, but on a meta level, you're assuming the upload succeeded, which is not a good idea. Always check the `['error']` parameter in the $_FILES array **BEFORE** you do ANYTHING with the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) is wrong for `$date`.
You will want to either pass `$date` to your function or make it a global varible

```
$date =  date( "Y_m_d_H_i_s_u" );

function upload($date) {
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $target = "uploads/" . $date . $info['extension'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

## or

```
$date =  date( "Y_m_d_H_i_s_u" );

function upload() {
    global $date;
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $target = "uploads/" . $date . $info['extension'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i make it global again?

Comment: I suggest not making it global but passing it to the function `upload($data){}` instead.

Comment: I want to make it global so i can use it at will in any function

Comment: why not just pass it to any function which needs it?

Comment: Making it global is the worst approach

Comment: Thanks guys.  Lots of help.  Will this make it global in all functions or do i have to do `global $date;` in every function i use it in

Comment: Would require adding it in each function. A global variable can be accessed anywhere and if updated will reflect anywhere that uses the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is my observation , you are having `scope` issues

```
$date =  date( "Y_m_d_H_i_s_u" );
```

Try if the date would always change

```
function upload() {
    $date =  date( "Y_m_d_H_i_s_u" );
    $info = pathinfo ( $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] );
    $target = "uploads/" . $date . $info ['extension'];
    if (move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'], $target )) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why make it a constant??? I don't see the purpose. Constant are not substitute for global variables (although they can be accessed gloabally. Logically, though, it's wrong)

Comment: I guess with wants all of them to have a constant time but the version would be different

Answer (score 1):

$date is outside of the scope of your function.
There are 2 ways to fix this:

### Option 1

```
$date = date( "Y_m_d_H_i_s_u" );

function upload() {
    globel $date;
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $target = "uploads/" . $date . $info['extension'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Option 2

```
$date = date( "Y_m_d_H_i_s_u" );

function upload($date) {
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $target = "uploads/" . $date . $info['extension'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

upload ($date);
```

Comment: i'm guessing that you want it to be `global $date;`, not `global data;`

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider returning `move_uploaded_file` directly

```
return move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)
```